# How could I build a tree array from this flat array in Javascript by their's parentId and Id.

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, tree

I have a flat array like this, I'm supposed to build a flat array for it. The object will be an children property of it's parent object if the pid is not null. How should I do this?

```
    var a = [
        {id: 1, pid: null}, 
        {id: 2, pid: 1}, 
        {id: 3, pid: 1}, 
        {id: 4, pid: 3}, 
        {id: 5, pid: 3}
     ];
```

Expect output:

```
     var result = [{id: 1, children: [
        {id: 2, children: []},
        {id: 3, children: [{id: 4}, {id: 5}]}
    ]}]
```

Comment: Have you [**tried anything so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both answers using reduce here are great, one slight issue is that there both multi-pass,  IOW: if the tree was very big there is going to be a lot of linear searching.

One solution to this is to first build a map, and then flatten the map..  mmm, actually flatten is probably the wrong word here, maybe expand.. :)  But you get the idea..

Below is an example.

```js
const a = [
    {id: 1, pid: null}, 
    {id: 2, pid: 1}, 
    {id: 3, pid: 1}, 
    {id: 4, pid: 3}, 
    {id: 5, pid: 3}
 ];
 
 
function flatern(map, parent) {
  const g = map.get(parent);
  const ret = [];
  if (g) {
    for (const id of g) {
      const k = {id};
      ret.push(k);
      const sub = flatern(map, id);
      if (sub) k.children = sub;
    }
    return ret;
  }
  return null;
}
     
function tree(a) {
  const m = new Map();
  a.forEach((i) => {
    const g = m.get(i.pid);
    if (!g) {
      m.set(i.pid, [i.id]);
    } else {
      g.push(i.id);
    }
  });
  return flatern(m, null);
}

console.log(tree(a));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: btw, my approach uses an object where no search takes place, because of hash table. access is O(1).

Comment: @NinaScholz  Nice one, must admit didn't really examine code in detail.. Your's look easier than mine so, I'm up-voting yours.. I'll keep mine here for those who find it easier to read / understand.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot. But I have a difficult time understanding what it means by"if (sub) k.children = sub;", could you explain why there is a () on sub?

Comment: It just means if there are any sub items, and them as children.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a single loop approach which works for unsorted arrays as well.

```js
var a = [{ id: 1, pid: null }, { id: 2, pid: 1 }, { id: 3, pid: 1 }, { id: 4, pid: 3 }, { id: 5, pid: 3 }],
    tree = function (data, root) {
        return data.reduce(function (o, { id, pid }) {
            o[id] = o[id] || { id };
            o[pid] = o[pid] || { id: pid };
            o[pid].children = o[pid].children || [];
            o[pid].children.push(o[id]);
            return o;
        }, {})[root].children;
    }(a, null);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Is there a way to get  not whole tree but a specifc child tree? getChildTree(array,id)?

Comment: @rendom, you could take the parent of the wanted id instead of `null` for the tree.

Comment: Is there way to convert tree back to list?

Comment: @rendom, yes it is possible by traversing the tree and handing over the parent.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reduce()` method and create recursive function.

```js
var a = [{id: 1, pid: null}, {id: 2, pid: 1}, {id: 3, pid: 1}, {id: 4, pid: 3}, {id: 5, pid: 3}];

function tree(data, parent) {
  return data.reduce((r, {id,pid}) => {
    if (parent == pid) {
      const obj = {id}
      const children = tree(data, id);
      if (children.length) obj.children = children;
      r.push(obj)
    }
    return r;
  }, [])
}

const result = tree(a, null);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm wondering what could I do if I want my output exactly like" var result =..........". I mean, starts with "var result ="

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.

Comment: now the output of your method is an array tree. what if I want something format like" var result =.....(the array tree goes here)".

Answer (score 0):

```
    var a = [
        {id: 1, pid: null}, 
        {id: 2, pid: 1}, 
        {id: 3, pid: 1}, 
        {id: 4, pid: 3}, 
        {id: 5, pid: 3}
    ];

    function processToTree(data) {
        const map = {};
        data.forEach(item => {
            map[item.id] = item;
            item.children = [];
        });

        const roots = [];
        data.forEach(item => {
            const parent = map[item.pid];
            if (parent) {
                parent.children.push(item);
            }
            else {
                roots.push(item);
            }
        });
        return roots;
    }
```

Learnt this method today, I think this is the best